# Fitting multimodal distributions in R; generating new values from fitted distribution

Tags: r, distribution, random, mixed-models

I am working with small sample size data:

```
>dput(dat.demand2050.unique)  
c(79, 56, 69, 61, 53, 73, 72, 86, 75, 68, 74.2, 80, 65.6, 60, 54)
```

for which the density distribution looks like this:
[image: pdf of data]

I know that the values are from two regimes - low and high - and assuming that the underlying process is normal, I used the `mixtools` package to fit a bimodal distribution:

```
set.seed(99)  
dat.demand2050.mixmdl <- normalmixEM(dat.demand2050.unique, lambda=c(0.3,0.7), mu=c(60,70), k=2)
```

which gives me the following result:
[image]
(the solid lines are fitted curves and the dashed line is the original density).

```
# get the parameters of the mixture
dat.demand2050.mixmdl.prop <- dat.demand2050.mixmdl$lambda    #mix proportions
dat.demand2050.mixmdl.means <- dat.demand2050.mixmdl$mu    #modal means
dat.demand2050.mixmdl.dev <- dat.demand2050.mixmdl$sigma   #modal std dev
```

The mixture parameters are:

```
>dat.demand2050.mixmdl.prop  #mix proportions  
[1] 0.2783939 0.7216061  
>dat.demand2050.mixmdl.means  #modal means  
[1] 56.21150 73.08389  
>dat.demand2050.mixmdl.dev  #modal std dev  
[1] 3.098292 6.413906
```

I have the following questions:

1. To generate a new set of values that approximates the underlying distribution, is my approach correct or is there a better workflow?
2. If my approach is correct, how can I use this result to generate a set of random values from this mixed distribution?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for CrossValidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidMarx yes, I debated that and even whether to cross-post, but ultimately decided to write here since my 2nd question is more about coding. However, I'd gladly do so if the mods think it is better suited there.

Comment: I am not sure if your approach is sensible. You do not specify what you plan to do with the random numbers. Also, your sample size is very small and estimating normal distributions from such small sample sizes is a bit dubious. Maybe the bootstrap would be a better approach for your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Roland true, the sample size is small but that is what I have. the data are from a set of studies and only so many. I thought of bootstrapping using `sample()`, but will have to go back to my notes why i did not take that approach..perhaps this part of the discussion should go on CrossValidated..

Comment: The question is what you want to infer from the random numbers. Your sample size might be too small to infer anything sensible from your approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sample size is a bit dubious to be fitting mixtures, but never mind that. You can sample from the fitted mixture as follows:

```
probs <- dat.demand2050.mixmdl$lambda
m <- dat.demand2050.mixmdl$mu
s <- at.demand2050.mixmdl$sigma

N <- 1e5
grp <- sample(length(probs), N, replace=TRUE, prob=probs)
x <- rnorm(N, m[grp], s[grp])
```

Comment: your method seems to overemphasize the lower distribution in the same way Roland's solution did. Compare your output density with the starting density and the output of @CnrL's solution. This code looks right, but the result seems off. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The results are exactly the same as @CnrL's. Run their solution with N = 1e5. As for the starting density; who knows what's going to happen with 15 data points.

Comment: @DavidMarx Both solutions don't give the same density plot as the original sample. That's a sample size problem.

Comment: see my comment on the question for why i am working with the small size. I ran @CnrL solution with the large N (check the link in my earlier comment) and it still gives a lower peak..

Comment: @HongOoi I don't get the same result for your solution as with CrnL's solution. Here's a comparison of the density I'm getting from your solution (N=1e5), his solution (N=1e5) and the original small dataset.: http://i.imgur.com/cMKnhhf.jpg

Comment: @DavidMarx Then you're doing something wrong. I just ran both with N=1e6 and got virtually identical results. In particular, make sure you're using the same bandwidth for everything.

Comment: Yeah, disregard. I just tried clearing out CrnL's example code and re-copy pasting and yours and his looks the same (and frankly, both look like Roland's deleted solution as well). Sorry forraising the alarm.

Comment: @AdvaitGodbole Nobody can access your Google drive. Regardless, all the answers here will give you the same solution (some may take a bit longer than others). If they don't happen to match what you intuitively think the density should look like, well... people have already pointed you to CrossValidated.

Comment: i assumed the links could be accessed, i havent used drive before. also, i ran your code again and it seems i made a was looking at the wrong plot earlier. so, yes it is giving me the expected shape. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is correct.

For each sample from your mixed distribution you just need to choose which of the two component Gaussian distributions the sample should come from and then draw the sample from that distribution.

You can choose between the two distributions using the mixture proportions you have found: simulate a random number between 0 and 1 and sample from the first distribution if it the random number is less than the first proportion, otherwise sample from the second distribution.

Finally, sample from the relevant Gaussian distribution using the rnorm function.

```
dat.demand2050.mixmdl.prop=c(0.2783939,0.7216061)
dat.demand2050.mixmdl.means=c(56.21150,73.08389)
dat.demand2050.mixmdl.dev=c(3.098292,6.413906)

sampleMixture=function(prop,means,dev){
    # Generate a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1
    # in order to choose between the two component distributions
    distTest=runif(1)
    if(distTest<prop[1]){
        # Then sample from the first component of the mixture
        sample=rnorm(1,mean=means[1],sd=dev[1])
    }else{
        # Sample from the second component of the mixture
        sample=rnorm(1,mean=means[2],sd=dev[2])
    }
    return(sample)
}

# Generate a single sample
sampleMixture(dat.demand2050.mixmdl.prop,dat.demand2050.mixmdl.means,dat.demand2050.mixmdl.dev)

# Generate 100 samples and plot resulting distribution
samples=replicate(100,sampleMixture(dat.demand2050.mixmdl.prop,dat.demand2050.mixmdl.means,dat.demand2050.mixmdl.dev))
plot(density(samples))
```

Comment: You're welcome.  No, it doesn't imply that.  This is because of the "if" condition.  Using runif() is only a way to introduce randomness into the choice between the distributions.  There is an exactly 28% chance that the value returned by runif() will be less than 0.28 (and conversely a 72% chance that it returns a value greater).  By checking whether runif is greater than or less than the first proportion (0.28 in this case) and choosing the first or second component of the mixture accordingly, we weight the probabilities correctly.

Comment: thanks, your solution seems to work well. However, doesnt the choice of `runif()` for `distTest` imply that it a value being from either distribution is equally probable, whereas the data (and the fit) suggest that the "probabilities" are about .3 and .7?

Comment: You should avoid the loop. Create 100 samples each from the two normal distributions and the uniform distribution and use `ifelse`.

Comment: @AdvaitGodbole Those probabilities are taken into consideration in the `if` statement. The function samples from the uniform distribution so that we randomly select from one mixture or the other, but that selection will occur as specified by those probabilites.

Comment: @Roland Your suggestion above would certainly make things faster and your answer below is very elegant, however I prefer the less speedy code above for this question as I think it makes it clearer to the OP how the sampling works.

Comment: @AdvaitGodbole I deleted the answer because after some testing and reading the documentation I was not absolutely certain that the sampling wouldn't be biased.

Comment: @Roland, ok perhaps that is what is causing the higher peak for the 'left' distribution..

Comment: @Roland I found the same thing, your earlier solution seems to overemphasize the lower distribution. I tried refactoring @CnrL's solution to use ifelse and found I got the same result: `sampleMixture=function(prop,means,dev, N){
  distTest=runif(N);
  l_sample = rnorm(N,mean=means[1],sd=dev[1]);
  u_sample = rnorm(N,mean=means[2],sd=dev[2]);
  sample = ifelse(distTest<prop[1], l_sample,u_sample);
  return(sample);
}`

Comment: Nevermind, I think your solution worked find @Roland, and I actually somehow mucked up CnrL's solution to give a different result.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would expect the two solutions to sample from the same distribution, I can't see a reason for a difference.

Comment: The difference was that I mucked something up in your code, which gave a less pronouncedly bimodal solution than it should have.

Comment: i am accepting @HongOoi's answer for 2 reasons - its less code and when i have multiple modes it will be easily extendable. however, as you rightly pointed out earlier, your answer was great to get an intuitive sense of the sampling process.